# APUE<2nd> 11.4,signal first or unlock first

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

which one is correct?
1.

```
pthread_mutex_lock
...
pthread_cond_broadcast
pthread_mutex_unlock
```

2.

```
pthread_mutex_lock
...
pthread_mutex_unlock
pthread_cond_broadcast
```

I know the second one condition may be changed during unlock to broadcast.
but what's the matter in the first one.can the thread be blocked?
is there some code to show the issue in the first one?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first sequence works fine. `pthread_cond_broadcast()` should be called after mutex is locked, and must unlock mutex in order for `pthread_cond_wait()` routine to complete.

You can find further explanation here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarOverview

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.